# Windows authentication + angular. Prevent login prompt

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6, windows-authentication

I'm tryng to authenticate my angular app with Windows auth. I make a call to an ***authorized*** api and wait for result to check if user is a windows user.

If user is authorized everything is ok, api return 200 status code.

If user is unauthorized a browser default login popup be shown. I want to intercept 401 response and show a custom error dialog, not the browser popup

There is a way to prevent login popup to be shown?

Thanks.

Here an example of my request:

```
var ret = this.http.get(this.baseUrl + this._hello, {headers: {'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest'}, withCredentials:true})
        .map(this.extractDataa)
        .catch(this.handleError);
```

Comment: You have not stated what's your problem? where exactly are you getting stuck?

Comment: "Il try to set 'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest' header " ..this header has nothing to do with authentication or authorisation

Comment: My problem is: I don't want that unauthorized user see login popup. I want to intercept 401 response and redirect user to login custom page.

Comment: I found a couple of response on stackoverflow where is said to use "X-Requested-With" to avoid login popup to be shown. But doesn't work

Comment: same issue I got, any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an `authenticated` (any variable name will work) variable in the .ts file of the component that contains the log-in pop-up, you can use that variable in the .html of the component.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="!authenticated">
  <app-login>/* log-in component */<app-login>
<ng-container>
```

This will only render the content in the `ng-container` if `authenticated` is `false`